# primefaces datatable row coloring

Tags: primefaces

I want to show datatable rows with different colors.

I am using rowStyleClass attribute.
But It is not changing the colors

My code in datatable is,

```
rowStyleClass="highlight";
```

and my css file is looks like this,

```
.highlight {
    background: yellow  !important ;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should have like two classes with different colors and use, in the rowStyleClass attribute, inline if:

```
rowStyleClass="#{(rowIndex mod 2) eq 0 ? 'highlight1' : 'highlight2'}"
```

Where "rowIndex" you should set in the datatable rowIndexVar attribute

```
rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
```

That means that even rows will have row style class set as 'highlight1' and odd rows - 'highlight2'

[See here more info](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/rowColor.xhtml)

Comment: isn't it easier to implement `.ui-datatable-odd` and `.ui-datatable-even` style classes in your CSS, which are implemented by `p:dataTable` by default?

Comment: you should also mention, that if you use themes then you should also overwrite/define the "background-image:none;" in your custom css

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way is to implement `.ui-datatable-odd` and `.ui-datatable-even` style classes in your CSS, which are implemented by `p:dataTable` by default.  Example:

```
.ui-datatable-odd {
    background: #ffffff;
}

.ui-datatable-even {
    background: #F2F5F9;
}
```

Ends up looking something like

[image]

It could be you need to use more specific selectors, read about css specificity for that

Answer (score 1):

Try this...It is working in my case

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-datatable-even{
    background: #F2F5F9;
}

.ui-widget-content .ui-datatable-odd{
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: You answer is 'identical' to the 12 upvoted one with a small difference that your selector is more specific. In these cases you can add a comment to the answer or propose an edit where you state that sometimes this is needed. (Like I did edit the answer now). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Tudor's answer is the correct way. In case you use treeTable you can do it this way:

```
.ui-treetable tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #edf2f6 !important;
}

.ui-treetable tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```